# How to execute script in administrator mode without prompt for selection from user side?

Tags: powershell, uac

I have a PowerShell script `Admin.PS1` which will open run `other.PS1` PowerShell script as adminnistarator. Code looks as follows:

```
$ScriptPath = "D:\usefull_PS_files\toNode\other.PS1"
$RelaunchArgs = '-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -file "' + $ScriptPath + '" -IsRunAsAdmin'
# Launch the process and wait for it to finish
try
{
    $AdminProcess = Start-Process "$PsHome\PowerShell.exe" -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList $RelaunchArgs
}
catch
{
    $Error[0] # Dump details about the last error
    exit 1
}
```

Now what happens is when I execute above PS script I get a PowerShell administrator prompt in which I have to select "yes" or "no", but what I actually want is `Other.PS1` to get execute as administrator without any prompt, i.e. without any need to select "yes" or "no".
So, how can I have way of running any PS script as administrator with no input from my side, in complete automated way.

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 options AFAICS:

- Disable UAC.
- Run the script from an already elevated prompt.
- Create a scheduled task with the checkbox "Run with highest privileges" enabled.

Comment: `psexec -h powershell.exe  -file other.ps1` could be another option

Comment: Definitely not recommended to disable UAC.

Comment: I most definitely do recommend disabling UAC in professional environments where you have admin accounts for administrative tasks and restricted accounts for regular users and day-to-day work. Home users is about the only area where UAC might have some benefit.

Comment: IMO UAC is a definite advantage even in professional environments because it discourages "run everything as admin" when logging on as admin. Disabling it undoes all the advantage it was designed for. I'm afraid we will simply have to agree to disagree.